# Rails named routes for the show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, named-routing

In my app I assign a url's `href` attribute as `profile_path` when using `resources :profiles` in my routes.rb file. I do not pass any id into `profile_path` yet the app somehow correctly assumes that it is the profile of the `current_user`. How does rails know this? Is this simply a default that rails assumes if you don't pass in an id?

Comment: actually I am using Devise for authentication, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: And the profile paths are set up as devise paths? That's how :)

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ umm I don't think they are...

Comment: You're saying that neither your routes, nor your models, have anything to do with devise?

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ as far as I can tell, not the profile model or routes...

Comment: And you don't have any devise filters/superclasses set up on any of your controllers? I'm confused; you say you have no devise routes, no devise in your models; did you use the view generators?

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ well these are the Devise routes I have enabled:   `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations'}`

Comment: And so I assume I'd be using Devise's superclasses for that, as well as its `current_user` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set up a before_filter in your controller with Devise where profile_path requires a user to sign in first, it will default to the current_user helper to send the current_user's id along with the request.

As an aside to the question's comment thread, to test what routes you have set up, run `rake routes` in terminal and you'll see if you have Devise routes set up.